# How to find the momentum of an object at time $T$ when velocity is not given?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum

[image: Question Problem]

I tried finding the change in momentum which is force x change in time. Here, I assumed the final momentum would be equal to change in momentum as since at $t= 0$, the object is at rest. However, I got the wrong answer. Did I miss something?

[image: My attempt]

Comment: You don't seem to do the necessary integral. Your equation $\Delta p =(T-0) F$ should read $dp= F\,dt$ so $\Delta p =\int F(t) dt$.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I left off the limits on the integral. It should be $\Delta p=\int_0^T F(t)dt$

Answer (score 1):

I’ll give you a sense of using integrals and how it’s needed here and **you can solve the problem yourself**. When the force is constantly changing you need to set-up an integral. An integral is a way of adding infinitesimal (super small) steps together. It is a type of summation

At the beginning, it is not moving. So the force at any time on in will be $F= X + Y t^{1/2}$ , but $X$ and $Y$ are constants, just numbers that don’t change. So the force depends only on t, and it keeps changing the whole time.

At any moment, the acceleration will be from the equation F = m a. So the acceleration changes continually too, since F does.

To get momentum we need velocity. How to find that? At any moment:

$$a = F / m = \frac{ X + Y t^{1/2}  }{m}$$

But, again, that keeps changing. Now if a was constant, the increase in speed over time would be $\Delta v= a \Delta t$ (a times elapsed time).

Over any tiny interval dt, we can assume a is constant. So over that tiny (infinitesimal) time dt, the increase in velocity will be acceleration, a, times elapsed time $dt. ~dv= a dt$

To add up these small changes in speed we integrate both sides: $\Delta v= \int_{0}^T a dt$, We integrate that from 0 to T (the “limits of integration”) Note that the limits of integration are always in the units of the last part, in this case dt, so we know they must be some times. To add from the start to the finish we use 0 and T. $\Delta v$ is the increase in velocity over that time. The sum of the tiny increases.

Maybe you can follow that procedure and do the problem. Let me know if you have a specific question that youve thought about but can’t get.

Comment: Hi, I see that you're new to this site. Just wanted to let you know that posting complete answers to homework questions is not allowed. Doing so does not help the asker at all.

Comment: @VincentThacker Ok thanks. Noted. Edited. (Technically i’ll disagree that i gave just a solution, and that it wouldnt have helped in this case. To follow it, he would have to read a half-lecture about whats happening and why, which would help, but I can fathom and follow site rules, and why we have such a rule)